# Using PreparedStatement in Try with Resources shows 'unknown class' error

Tags: java, jdbc, try-with-resources

I am initialising a prepared statement globally (so it isn't pre-compiled everytime a function is run, only when the application is loaded), and attempting to use the preparedstatement in a try with resources, but it is showing an 'unknown class' error. This is the code:

```
private PreparedStatement ingredientDelete;

public void deleteIngredient(String name) {
    try(ingredientDelete = con.prepareStatement(DELETE_INGREDIENT_BY_NAME)){
        ingredientDelete.setString(1, name);
        ingredientDelete.execute();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Delete failed - " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

For clarity the connection is opened in another method and also declared globally.

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: All I'm getting in the bottom menu of intellij is this 'Error:(142, 29) java: <identifier> expected' which is pointing at the end of 'ingredientDelete' just before the = sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't valid Java. The resourced declared in the try must be local variables, and thus have their type declared. See [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)

```
Resource:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclaratorId = Expression
```

Making it a field doesn't make sense anyway, since a statement is bound to a connection, and since you're re-creating it every time the method is called anyway, thus potentially using the same statement in multiple threads.

You're pre-optimizing, which is the root of all evil. The database already has a cache of prepared statements. No need to do that by yourself. And you should definitely use a connection pool, too, instead of using a single connection for all your program.

Comment: That makes sense, I just watched a video that said it was good practice to make a preparedStatement a field, due to its performance gains over a regular Statement being because it is pre-compiled, and therefore pre-compiling it at every method call would negate that improvement.
Also could you please link me to a tutorial or article that explains how to use connection pools please, not heard of this.

Comment: Try-with closes resources automatically. So, if the try code works correctly and close is called, then any code after try will fail because the resource is closed. Is that why it makes sense to limit the scope of try ?